# Is arithmetic on pointers associative?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

If I say,

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p = a;
```

Now, If I write `p + 1 + 2` will it be same as `((p + 1) + 2)`? Any standard reference which proves this wrong?

Comment: Addition associates left-to-right, so `p+1+2` is certainly equivalent to `(p+1)+2`. What's more interesting is whether it's equivalent to `p+(1+2)`.

Comment: @Yappie: `p++` is NOT the same as `p+1`. The former changes the value of `p`.

Answer (score 4):

Only if you don't go out of range. For instance, in this:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p = (a + 10) - 9;
int *q = a + (10 - 9);
```

The assignment to `p` invokes undefined behaviour, whereas the assignment to `q` doesn't.

As long as you stay in range, though, you'd expect associativity to hold.

Incidentally, note that in your question the two things you give are the same by definition, since addition (well, in-range addition anyway) is left-associative. That is, `x + y + z == (x + y) + z`, not `x + (y + z)`.

Comment: Likewise, the behavior of 1+(a-b) may be defined even when (1+a) would not.  I'm not sure if it's possible for (1+a)-b to be defined when (a-b) wouldn't be, though it's conceivable.  I'm not sure in what cases a pointer's "provenance" is allowed to affect what can be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

> §3.7.4.3
>
> 2 `A pointer value is a safely-derived pointer to a dynamic object only if it has pointer-to-object type and it is
>   one of the following: ... the result of well-defined pointer arithmetic (5.7) using a safely-derived pointer value;`
>
> § 5.7
>
> 3 `The result of the binary + operator is the sum of the operands.`

Sounds legit to me.

Comment: Can you link to where you found this?

Comment: The draft is free at [ISO](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).  The final you pay for at [ISO](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/)  (Most people use the draft)

Comment: If you're really cunning, you grabbed a copy of n3290 while it was free from ISO. That's the FDIS, i.e. the draft that was voted to become the standard. It should be that the only difference between the FDIS and the standard is the formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure that's cunning quite so much as lucky timing.  I didn't have lucky timing :(

Answer (score 2):

Addition between a pointer and an integer is defined in C++11 as follows (5.7/5):

> if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the
>   expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the
>   value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist.

The next sentence talks about pointers one past the end of arrays.

So, addition involving pointers is "the same thing as" addition involving indexes, which of course is associative. From this you can deduce that, provided the array elements exist (or are one past the end), then addition involving pointers is associative.

If your arithmetic exceeds the bounds of the array that the pointer points into, then behavior is undefined, and hence in particular need not be associative.

Answer (score 1):

I beieve that yes in practice, but perhaps no in theory.

You are asking if `p + 3` is the same as `((p + 1) + 2)` but the standard says that pointer arithmetic only makes sense inside an array or just one element past its end.

Comment: At the very least, it's 'no' for iterators - I've been bitten by that in the past. I haven't personally been bitten by it with pointers, so it may be more of a theoretical than practical problem, but I'd err on the side of caution.

Comment: The question was about pointers to `int`-s without mention of iterators.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I upvoted you :) I'm just mentioning it in passing because it's a related issue.

Comment: Why do you think that iterators are pointer-like? They are not -except for the notation (infix `*` and `++`).

Comment: I don't think they're pointer-like. The notation is the point here: consider `vec.begin() + 10 - 9` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are really just numbers, so yes addition will be associative in the way you are describing.

EDIT: See comment below from delnan - while yes, the addition will be associative, my statement that pointers are just numbers is not quite correct.

Comment: If you treat pointers as just numbers, you venture into the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Aren't they just addresses?

Comment: Exactly, they are addresses with a type. Not numbers. For instance, `p+1` gives you a pointer to the storage location after `p` - of the same type as the previous one - and not the next natural number.

Comment: That's a good point and an important distinction. Thanks for clarifying. I'll edit my post to make sure readers see this.